# Excel 2010 - Visual Basic to find minimum and maximum values in colored cells

Tags: excel, vba

- I want to find the minimum and maximum values in a excel range
- Only in the colored yellow cells, the cells without color will not be considered for find the max and min values**
- The range with the colored cells is range A:A**

*I have made this code, but it only returns an empty cell in D5 and E5 cells.*

**Does anybody has an idea what i am missing here?**

*many thanks*

**EDIT**

I made debug and all variables are empty, **except `amarelosMin` and `i_max` that both had value 2** -I don't understand why.

My range values in A:A goes from 1 to 20, and the yellow values are 2,3,4 and 5. If the code was correct it should give me 2 and 5, has min and max values.

```
Dim amarelosMin As Range
Dim vAmarelosmMin As Variant
ReDim vAmarelosmMin(Range("A1:A3").Rows.count - 1)
For Each amarelosMin In ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
If amarelosMin.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then

    i_min = LBound(vAmarelosmMin)
    i_max = UBound(vAmarelosmMin)

    Max = vAmarelosmMin(i_min)
    Min = vAmarelosmMin(i_min)
    For i = i_min + 1 To i_max
        If vAmarelosmMin(i) > Max Then
            Max = vAmarelosmMin(i)
        ElseIf vAmarelosmMin(i) < Min Then
            Min = vAmarelosmMin(i)
        End If
    Next

End If
Next amarelosMin
ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = "Minimo dos valores a amarelo"
ActiveSheet.Range("D5") = Min
ActiveSheet.Range("E5") = Max
```

Comment: Yes, my color index test is correct has 6 is the yellow color. Also i have a piece of code that sums all the values in yellow and it works very well with the same line of code to make the test.

Comment: what is the actual range you are looking at in column A?

Comment: A2:A5, with values 2,3,4,5. This is the range yellow colored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that your variant array is unncessary and is not actually storing any values as you loop.

You can simplify your code to this range loop, which also looks just at the used portion of column A rather than every cell

```
Sub Recut
Dim amarelosMin As Range
Dim dbMin As Double
Dim dbMax As Double

dbMin = Application.Max(Range("A:A"))
dbMax = Application.Min(Range("A:A"))

For Each amarelosMin In Range([a1], Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If amarelosMin.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        If amarelosMin.Value < dbMin Then
            dbMin = amarelosMin.Value
        Else
            If amarelosMin.Value > dbMax Then dbMax = amarelosMin.Value
        End If
    End If
Next amarelosMin

ActiveSheet.Range("C5") = "Minimo dos valores a amarelo"
ActiveSheet.Range("D5") = dbMin
ActiveSheet.Range("E5") = dbMax
End Sub
```

Comment: SOLVED. Many thanks to brettdj for the time and good fix to my issue. Now it throws min and max values correctly.